# Updating Bind with nsupdate works locally, not remotely or on private IP

Tags: bind, ddns, nsupdate

I am attempting to get nsupdate/RFC2136 working for a remote BIND server, but I've been scratching my head for two days trying to figure out what is going on.

BIND 9.16.23 is running on an internal server, no apparmor, no firewall. Here are the relevant sections of the BIND configuration:

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/named";

  listen-on { any; };

  allow-query { any; };

  recursion no;

  blackhole { acl_bogusnets; };

  // DNSSEC
  dnssec-validation yes;

  // hide version
  version "not provided";

  key-directory "/etc/named/keys";

  auth-nxdomain no;
};

controls {
  inet 192.168.131.21 port 953 allow { any; } keys { "key_ddns"; };
  inet 192.168.131.21 allow { any; } keys { "key_ddns"; };
  inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

zone "mydomain.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/primary/com/mydomain/db.mydomain.com";

    update-policy {
      grant key_ddns name _acme-challenge.www.mydomain.com. txt;
    };

    notify yes;

    dnssec-policy  "default";
    inline-signing yes;
    key-directory  "/var/named/keys";
  };
```

I started by copying the two keys (rndc and key_ddns) to a local folder and created a file with the nsupdate commands to add a record (add.txt):

```
server 127.0.0.1
debug yes
zone mydomain.com
update add _acme-challenge.www.mydomain.com. 300 IN TXT "TEST"
show
send
```

Here are the different commands that were executed and the associated results. Everything below are all executed on the local BIND server.

```
nsupdate -k ./rndc.key add.txt or nsupdate -k ./rndc.key -v add.txt
update: info: client @0x7ff7a0636e18 127.0.0.1#49496/key rndc-key: view view_primary_ns: updating zone 'mydomain.com/IN': update failed: rejected by secure update (REFUSED)

nsupdate -k ./key_ddns.key add.txt or nsupdate -k ./key_ddns.key -v add.txt
update: info: client @0x7ff7a061a0e8 127.0.0.1#37881/key key_ddns: view view_primary_ns: updating zone 'mydomain.com/IN': adding an RR at '_acme-challenge.www.mydomain.com' TXT "TEST"
```

So I assume this means the key_ddns key as working as expected as the record is successfully added. Here's where I get stuck. If add.txt is changed from 127.0.0.1 to the private IP 192.168.131.21, then the following occurs:

```
nsupdate -k ./rndc.key add.txt or nsupdate -k ./key_ddns.key add.txt
nsupdate error: Communication with 192.168.131.21#53 failed: timed out

nsupdate -k ./rndc.key -v add.txt or nsupdate -k ./key_ddns.key -v add.txt
nsupdate error: Communication with 192.168.131.21#53 failed: unexpected error
Bind logs:
general: error: Accepting TCP connection failed: connection refused
general: error: TCP connection failed: connection refused
```

If add.txt is changed from 192.168.131.21 to 192.168.131.21 953, then the following occurs:

```
nsupdate -k ./rndc.key add.txt or nsupdate -k ./key_ddns.key add.txt
nsupdate error: Communication with 192.168.131.21#53 failed: timed out

nsupdate -k ./rndc.key -v add.txt or nsupdate -k ./key_ddns.key -v add.txt
nsupdate error: Communication with 192.168.131.21#53 failed: unexpected error
Bind logs:
general: error: invalid command from 192.168.131.21#39997: out of range
```

I am completely stumped as to why I can't get nsupdate to work with it's private IP.